# Selecting last row in database not working using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a php code that will select the last row in mysql using database but this error comes out:

```
 syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE)
```

My php code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","productno") or die("Error " .     mysqli_error($con));

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Alibaba FROM records ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    $s_Alibaba = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $sql_Alibaba = $s_Alibaba[0]; //Compare with the last record
}   

echo $sql_Alibaba;
```

Any idea how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Which `$result` is it talking about? You have three `$results` in your code.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Alibaba FROM records ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1");//should be this one

Comment: what will be output if you echo mysqli-error? `echo mysqli_error($con)` after the query?

Comment: Try to execute your sql query on database server to check the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `date` is a reserved keyword in mysql. Escape it with ` characters around:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Alibaba FROM records ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html